# Load video and play Angular 9

Tags: angular

I have created a video and added to my site as a background video, but I didn't want to even load it on mobile so I did this:

```
<video #video autoplay muted loop id="video" *ngIf="currentWidth && currentWidth >= 992">
    <source [src]="section.backgroundVideo" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And in my code I did this:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event: any) {
    this.currentWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
}

public currentWidth: number;

constructor(private backgroundImageService: BackgroundImageService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Which sortof works. The problem is that sometimes my video doesn't automatically play when it's loaded.
So I did this:

```
@ViewChild('video', { static: true }) videoplayer: ElementRef;

ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (!this.videoplayer) return;
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
}
```

But it never finds the videoPlayer. I suspect it's because it's not updated even if the **currentWidth** is greater than 992px.
Does anyone know how I can achieve my desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be **static: false**

```
@ViewChild('video', { static: false }) videoplayer: ElementRef;
```

because element is under ngIf and cannot be requested statically